# Adding a row to Google Spreadsheet via cURL - required fields errors

Tags: xml, curl, google-drive-api

So the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row) say very plainly that POSTing XML to the list feed url for the sheet with the field names in the format of this XML will insert a new row.

Auth is working and authorized account can access sheet.  All those errors are resolved.

So when I post to https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/mySheetIDHere/private/full without  I get

"The posted entry is missing one or more of the required field(s): title"

So I added `<title></title>` in addition to the previously existing `<gsx:Title></gsx:Title>` and that goes away but is replaced by

"The posted entry is missing one or more of the required field(s): rowCount"

So I tried adding an int that is the current row count but that error persists.

Current XML is below

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">
  <title>A Title</title>
  <rowCount>3</rowCount>
  <gsx:Title>A Title</gsx:Title>
  <gsx:Name>A Name</gsx:Name>
  <gsx:Email>An email</gsx:Email>
  <gsx:Phone>A phone</gsx:Phone>
</entry>
```

The docs say nothing about required fields or row counts.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am encountering the same errors, ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

Got it working, here's [a Gist with all of my scripts](https://gist.github.com/kristjan/fa3dce7f3128b225e47a). From your URL, it looks like you might be POSTing to the [add a worksheet](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_worksheet) endpoint instead of the [add a list row](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row) endpoint. The worksheet endpoint expects `title` and `rowCount` like you're seeing. What you want is a URL that looks like

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$spreadsheet_id/$worksheet_id/private/full
```

I set up [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QG5xPBsIy5BHOvMBzgr_iSHAcx24HPgcg_B3GMh3qt4/edit?usp=sharing) to test with three columns:

- Fruit
- Color
- Size

I seeded it (hah!) with `Apple, Red, Medium` as I tested auth and reading, then added `Orange, Orange, Medium` with this cURL command:

```
curl \
  --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$auth" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/atom+xml' \
  -d @data.xml \
  -X POST \
  "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$spreadsheet_id/$worksheet_id/private/full"
```

Where:

- `$auth` is my Google auth token obtained from `https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin`
- `$spreadsheet_id` is the ID visible in the URL or obtained from `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full`
- `$worksheet_id`is the worksheet (one sheet/tab inside the whole document) obtained from `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/$spreadsheet_id/private/full`. I didn't see anywhere visible in the UI I could get the worksheet ID.

and `data.xml` looks like this:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">
  <gsx:fruit>Orange</gsx:fruit>
  <gsx:color>Orange</gsx:color>
  <gsx:size>Medium</gsx:size>
</entry>
```

I noticed that the columns have all been lowercased - I'm not sure if that matters. I also noticed there are `title` and `content` tags when I fetch the rows, in addition to the structured elements, but that `title` was a red herring for the `title` error you're seeing.

```
<!-- GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/$spreadsheet_id/$worksheet_id/private/full -->
<!-- snip -->
  <title type="text">Apple</title>
  <content type="text">color: Red, size: Medium</content>
  <gsx:fruit>Apple</gsx:fruit>
  <gsx:color>Red</gsx:color>
  <gsx:size>Medium</gsx:size>
<!-- snip -->
```

Comment: Now that Google no longer supports ClientLogin, how do you retrieve Authorization Token?

Comment: Looks like we've got to switch to [OAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize)

Answer (score 2):

I was simply using the wrong URL - instead of referencing the List feed link element with rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post", I was referencing the Worksheet feed, which has also has a link element with the same rel but a different href.

From what I gather, the list feed URL and the list feed POST URL are the same, which is where the confusion began for me.

Comment: Generally in REST-like APIs, you see those URLs being the same. The important difference is the verb, asking to GET the resource or POST a new one. There's a nice, simple summary of RESTful behavior in the [Rails routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: I know how REST like APIs work and I was in fact using the POST command. As I stated, I was referencing the wrong URL, not performing a GET.